# Convert Object's array to HTML table in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of object like this :

```
var entryList = [
  {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
    "Key3": "Value3"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
    "Key3": "Value3"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2",
    "Key3": "Value3"
  }
]
```

And I want to create a HTML tab like this :

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  Key1  |  Key2  |  Key3  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| Value4 | Value5 | Value6 |
| Value7 | Value8 | Value9 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

And sort the values by key when we click on the header

3/4 of the code is in the html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

<thead>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.entryList[0]">
                <a ng-click="$ctrl.sortType = key; $ctrl.sortReverse = !$ctrl.sortReverse">
                    {{key}}
                    <span ng-show="$ctrl.sortType == key && !$ctrl.sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                    <span ng-show="$ctrl.sortType == key && $ctrl.sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="itemFormData in $ctrl.entryList | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchForm">
            <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in itemFormData">{{ itemFormData[key] }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

The table is correctly displayed but when I click on the header to sort the column nothing happens. If you have some suggestions and thank you for your time.

Comment: what if you try to group your data?

Comment: Create a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)  you can find the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cfhzub2y/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting code directly in `ng-click`, make a function in your controller. That's what a controller is for!

```
<a ng-click="selectSortType(key)">

$scope.selectSortType = function(key) {
  $scope.sortType = key; 
  $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cfhzub2y/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer, I didn't know ng-click not allow multiple instructions